# Dropdown menu broke

Tags: html, css, menu

I have being trying to find a solution with a menu i have on a custom html website that it is not appearing but i can't for some reason find a solution and i'm quite curious what i'm doing wrong.

```
<div class="header_area fix" id="header">           
<div class="header_top fix">
    <div class="left_logo floatleft fix">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Burning Desire Stoves Fireplace and Fire Centre" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="main_menu floatright fix">
        <button style="floatright" id="mobile_button">Menu</button>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="showroom.php">Showroom</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Stoves</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="stovesWood.php">Woodburning Stoves</a></li>
                <li><a href="stovesMulti.php">Multifuel Stoves</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="fireplaces.php">Fireplaces</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fires</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="firesGas.php">Gas Fires</a></li>
                <li><a href="firesElec.php">Electric Fires</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="testimonial.php">Case Studies</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can check the website [here](http://www.pixel.house/burningdesire/)
The site is a for a client of mine he said he added some extra menu option without touching the css and then the menu broke. More importanly the dropdown of the menu is not appearing and i was trying to make come the surface with some display:block or z-index with no luck.

Also he has add a PHP CMS called Couch which is  adding  tag.

To give you a better idea the following code as actually a snippet and it is located in a most likely cms path "editor/snippets/header"

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant to the production code, but for this example, you're missing a closing </div> for #header.

Comment: I didn't paste all the code it seems ( i gave it a look and it is there)

Comment: Please edit your question and make the HTML like it is on your site then.

Comment: At the bottom of the page it mentions CouchCMS - a system for developing HTML, and I don't see the CSS. So I think we're missing a lot of info on this question.

Comment: I thought that would be a problem if i dont mention it since the problem is in css but here is the full info i have from him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.main-menu>ul>li>ul  {
     position:absolute;

 }
```

Your Menu Has a Dropwown but it is not hidden ,  so it takes some space. and the header has oveflow hidden, so the menu is becoming hidden entirely.

Add this css and your menu will be shown,

but you need to add code for dropdown to work.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS is all kinds of jacked up.

The issues:

- `overflow: hidden` on the `.fixed` element is causing the text to disappear.
- As far as I can tell, there's no CSS that displays the drop down lists on hover
- The drop down lists aren't hidden, so they're taking up space forcing the main list out of the nav bar
- There's still `list-style-type:disc` for the `li` elements

I'll fiddle with it for a minute, but those are the issues.

**Update** I fiddled with the CSS and got the dropdowns to display. You'll have to make them look pretty with some CSS, but they're working. Yeah, it's *kind* of hacky, but I did what I could with the 5? CSS sheets all competing for screen time.

```
    /* menu extra css */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-hidden {
  display:block;
}
.dropdown-hidden {
  float: none!important;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999999;
  left: 0px;
  background: #fff;
}
.dropdown-hidden li {
  display: block;
  float: none!important;
  position: relative;
}
.fix {
  overflow: inherit!important;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

-

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="showroom.php">Showroom</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="index.html#">Stoves</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-hidden">
        <li><a href="stovesWood.php">Woodburning Stoves</a></li>
        <li><a href="stovesMulti.php">Multifuel Stoves</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="fireplaces.php">Fireplaces</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#">Fires</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-hidden">
        <li><a href="firesGas.php">Gas Fires</a></li>
        <li><a href="firesElec.php">Electric Fires</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="testimonial.php">Case Studies</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @user3246028 I've updated my answer in case you missed it or haven't figured it out already.